# Link multiple user databases together?

Tags: database, mysql, wp-user-query

Okay, so I am helping in website design and social media aspect of a game my friends are developing, and I want to be able to sync my Wordpress user database, game wiki user db and the game's database.

This is so anyone downloading the (very) large file to install the game can set up their profile, avatar, purchase in-game items, etc on the Wordpress site while waiting on it to download. And the wiki side, it will give the same users with the same gamer tag a way to help update or comment on the wiki articles if it hasn't been done by the devs.

I know it's a query, but I am unsure how to set it up.

Comment: have you looked into multisite installs? The same install with the same user database can serve multiple websites, each with different theme/plugins and content, but the same users and user meta

Comment: I only know of WP multi site. This is to sync users between 2 websites which only 1 is Wordpress platform, the other is MediaWiki platform, and 1 PC MMO game server.

Comment: You didn't mention the other 2 sites were not WordPress, what you want may not be possible, you would need to pick one then make the other 2 use it, or, rely on some form of single sign on/federated login such as OAuth, the kind of login that lets you use FB or Google

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.